# Difference between @aware and @props directives in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9, laravel-components

The `@aware` Laravel Blade template directive was introduced in Laravel 8, but I still don't understand what it does differently from the already existing `@props` directive.

For instance, if I use a Blade template like this:

```html
<x-view-content :page="$page ?? ''" />
```

and the component used above is defined in **views/components/view-content.blade.php** like this:

```html
@aware(['page'])

<div>
    {{ $page }}
</div>
```

I get the page successfully rendered inside the component. However, replacing `@aware(['page'])` with `@props(['page'])` produces the same result.

I would like to know what the differences between them are.

Comment: [Accessing Parent Data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#accessing-parent-data) explains it

Comment: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#accessing-parent-data)

Comment: @brombeer, yes, it does explain it, but the benefit of introducing the `@aware` directive isn't clear. Does it then mean I can replace all `@aware` directives with `@props` without breaking my code but I can't do it the other way around (replace all `@props` directives with `@aware` )?

Comment: @UdoE. you seem to be missing the point about parent and child components. You use `@aware` when you want to **access a parent's data from a child component**. In the example you provided, there's only one component and yes both `aware` and `props` will work because there're no children components which uses the data from your view-content component.

Answer (score 0):

`@aware` is for accessing data from a parent component where you have `@props`. You can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#accessing-parent-data) all relevant information. In your case you don't have child component.